# Laravel register doesn't log user in

Tags: authentication, registration, laravel

So i've looked at loads and loads of information on how to register and how to log in with laravel, Ive got my user to register successfully & separately log in successfully. However when you register, it doesn't consider you as logged in, and no matter what i try i cant seem to get it work.

This is my login:

```
$userdata = array(
    'username'      => Input::get('email'),
    'password'      => Input::get('password')
);

if ( Auth::attempt($userdata) ) {
        return Redirect::to('home');
    }  else  {
        return Redirect::to('login')
        ->with('login_errors', true);
    }
```

Which works as intended, no problems.

here is my register:

```
$user = new User;
$user->username = Input::get('username');
$user->email    = Input::get('email');
$user->password = Hash::make('password');   
$user->save();

    return Redirect::to('home');
```

This also works, as in the user is created, the user can then choose to log in. however if i add the exact same `Auth::attempt()`, it fails, all other `Auth::check()`s checks ive tried fail. What is it im doing wrong?

Comment: Doest it show any error messages?

Comment: No, i just dont have access to the user after the registration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Auth::attempt() expects an array like you mention, why not just get back the $user you just created as an array and pass it to the attempt method before you redirect? Again, not familiar with Laravel but based on your code samples I would think this should work.. something like this maybe:

```
$user = new User;
$user->username = Input::get('username');
$user->email    = Input::get('email');
$user->password = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));
$user->save();

$userdata = array(
    'username'      => $user->username,
    'password'      => $user->password
);

if ( Auth::attempt($userdata ) ) {
        return Redirect::to('home');
    }
```

Comment: no offense here but you misunderstaned him, the first example what he showd is logging in, the second is the register, he just showd that works, what you provided is, you tied the registration and login together

Comment: the Auth::attempt expects an array, if i pass $user it will error

Comment: @LeventeNagy I think he wants them to be logged in after they register

Comment: you are right @tai, when they are registered, i should have access to their user, they shouldnt need to then log in. Ive tried what you have suggested already with the same results, after the answer rob gave i changed my input to include the hash on the password, but my problem seems to be, it only accepts password as the password, if i do that it registers fine `{{ Form::label('password', 'Password') . Form::password('password') }}` theres my form, any ideas?

Comment: This. If you want them to be logged in right after register, then you would need to call the login method as part of a successful registration action.

Answer (score 1):

Hash::make() does not retrieve the posted value of the given argument.

Instead of `Hash::make('password');`, try `Hash::make(Input::get('password'));`.
My gues is that your user now has the password 'password' instead of what they filled in the registration form.

Comment: you are right in the sense that, if i put the password as password it works, however changing this to what you suggests doesn't change this. if i put a password of something other than password it doesnt log in, any suggestions?